# Complimentary accent color in XAML - UWP Windows 10

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, xamlparseexception

I'm trying to get a button to change colour once an action is taken. My button's background is set to `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush` and I basically want to get the 'opposite/complementary' colour once it is clicked.

I found this article:

[Using a complimentary accent color](http://www.mrlacey.com/2013/03/using-complimentary-accent-color.html)

Which seems like what I was looking for. I've had to modify the code a bit as it seems to be specific to windows phone rather than UWP. Below is the class I changed but note that I did not include the entire code from the article above as it was left unchanged:

```
public class AccentComplimentBrush : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The resource name - as it can be referenced by within the app
    /// </summary>
    private const string ResourceName = "AccentComplimentBrush";

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see 
        cref="AccentComplimentBrush"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public AccentComplimentBrush()
    {
        try
        {
            //// This doesn't work in the designer - so don't even try
            if (this.IsInDesignMode)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Make sure we don't try and add the resource more than once - would 
            //happen if referenced on multiple pages or in app and page(s)
            if (!Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(ResourceName))
            {
                var currentAccentColorHex = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush"];

                var hsl = HslColor.FromColor(currentAccentColorHex.Color);
                hsl.ConvertToCompliment();

                Color compliment = hsl.ToColor();

                Application.Current.Resources.Add(ResourceName, new SolidColorBrush(compliment));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something went wrong - ask for your money back");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it's called from XAML:

1. First the class is initialized (and it gets initialized ok)

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <common:AccentComplimentBrush x:Key="AccentComplimentBrush" />
   </UserControl.Resources>
   ```
2. When it goes through the code of the above class, it finds the relevant resource, gets the relevant colour, gets the complementary colour and converts it back to a resource and adds it to the application's resource. As mentioned, I've checked all of that and it all works fine.

Note that it's a circular button and it contains an ellipse which is where I'm trying to assign the stroke and fill properties to the new brush:

```
<Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource AccentComplimentBrush}"
         Fill="{StaticResource AccentComplimentBrush}"
         StrokeThickness="2">
</Ellipse>
```

This is the error I get:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>   Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape.Fill'. [Line: 301 Position: 46]

From the error it looks like it has a problem assigning the 'brush' that's generated by the class.

Note that the `Ellipse` code works just fine if I hardcode a `ThemeResource` or an actual colour.

Any ideas how I can resolve this? Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simply modifying the `Key` to anything other than `AccentComplimentBrush`.

```
<common:AccentComplimentBrush x:Key="whatever" />
```

Yes, ***inside*** the constructor of the `AccentComplimentBrush` class, the complimentary color (a SolidColorBrush) is first added to the resource dictionary with the key `AccentComplimentBrush`.

But ***after*** the constructor has finished, an instance of `AccentComplimentBrush class` (which is a subclass of ViewModelBase) is added to the resource dictionary with the same key, and replace your complimentary color.

So eventually XAML will assign a ViewModelBase to the Fill property at runtime, thus the error.

Comment: I thought I had tried it before, but tried again t just in case and I still get the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It is working fine after I modify the key name, please get my code from [OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1QiW2PS) and check it yourself.

Comment: That's weird! I've downloaded your sample and I thought it was because you were assigning this static resource to the grid's background instead of a button, but I've just copied/pasted my button and it's working as expected but I can't figure out for the live of me why it still isn't working for me. I spent the last hour or so going back and forth, comparing the 2 and can't see any difference. My class is definitely initialized, but it still telling it can't find that resource. I'll keep researching it and update when I find out what it is! Probably something silly as usual!

Comment: Getting stranger by the minute. Now, my class will not get initialized and it's probably why I'm still getting this error, but I know it was getting initialized originally before I posted this issue. Driving me mad! I'll keep on looking!

Comment: It appears this was my problem all along. I'm confused as to how I missed that, but my AccentComplimentBrush is not being initialized when I thought it was and that's really the problem. I still can't figure out why it's not being initialized when my other resources i.e. viewmodels and converters are, but for now my work-around is to create the class in the view before the InitializeComponents is called and this resolved the problem. I will create a separate question for this issue if I can't figure this out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Thierry is there a controltemplate involved? I think I may need all your xaml code to reproduce your issue